# Should I use volatile if I use synchronized

Tags: java

Should I use `volatile` every time if I use `synchronized` dealing with some `mutable state`.

1. `synchronized` makes me (state/threads) safe
2. `volatile` makes threads updated about `shared mutable state`.

Then I should put `volatile` everywhere If I care about threads to be updated?

**EDIT: There are two use cases:**

**1.**

**1000 threads read and write to this object** (they hope they are updated about state `a`):

```
 class A {
   private int a;
   public synchronized int getA() {...}
   public void setA(int a) {...}
 }
```

**2.**

**There are 1000 threads of ThreadA.** They hope they are updated about state `a`

```
class ThreadA extends Thread {
 private int a;
 public void run() { synchronized(a) { ... } }
}
```

Comment: See http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_volatile.shtml

Comment: @nitegazer2003 I think he knows what volatile means

Comment: Volatile prior to Java 1.5 might have been the way to go (obviously situation dependent) but I'd personally suggest making use of locks and atomic operations where possible instead.

Comment: `volatile` acts like a `synchronised` block around every access to the variable, locked over the variable. What is your particular use case?

Comment: Agree with @Quetzalcoatl, if it's a variable, consider using something like `AtomicXXX` where `XXX` is your variable type (i.e. `AtomicBoolean`)

Comment: I'm not sure what you are really asking, but generally you don't have to declare field volatile if 1) it is used only in one thread, 2) it is final, 3) access to this variable can happen only in synchronized blocks.

Comment: According to http://jeremymanson.blogspot.com/2008/11/what-volatile-means-in-java.html yes, you should.

Comment: @AdamSiemion The "What volatile means in Java" article refers to the double-checked locking idiom. It refers to a different problem: accessing mutable shared state *without* synchronization every time. It's not valid to conclude that you should always use volatile when using synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

Like many performance questions, the real issue is simplicity and clarity.  I suggest using synchronized or volatile as using both is likely to be confusing. Using both is redundant and thus slightly inefficient, but unlikely to be enough to matter.  I would worry more about making the code as easy to understand as possible, and do no more than you need to do.

In your first case, only volatile makes sense (or using synchronized consistently)

```
class A {
   private volatile int a;
   public int getA() {...}
   public void setA(int a) {...}
 }
```

In your second case synchronizing on a local object makes no sense, you can remove it.  I wouldn't extends Thread either, this is bad practice.

While you might have 1000 threads you are only likely to have 8-16 CPUs Have so many CPU bound threads is a bad idea.  Reduce the number of threads and you are likely to improve performance by reducing the overhead.

You should design them to be as independent as possible because if you can't it is likely that a single thread will be faster as it won't have the cache consistency over head.

---

IMHO Using a enum is simpler than using Guava MemorizeSupplier but which is faster

```
public class GuavaMain {
    interface AAA {
        int hashCode();
    }

    enum Singleton implements AAA {
        INSTANCE
    }

    public static void main(String... ignored) {
        Supplier<AAA> memoize = Suppliers.memoize(new Supplier<AAA>() {
            @Override
            public AAA get() {
                return new AAA() {
                };
            }
        });

        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            int runs = 5000;
            long time1 = System.nanoTime();
            for (int i = 0; i < runs; i++) {
                // call a method on out lazy instance
                Singleton.INSTANCE.hashCode();
            }
            long time2 = System.nanoTime();
            for (int i = 0; i < runs; i++) {
                // call a method on out lazy instance
                memoize.get().hashCode();
            }
            long time3 = System.nanoTime();
            System.out.printf("enum took %,d ns and memorize took %,d ns avg%n",
                    (time2 - time1) / runs, (time3 - time2) / runs);
        }
    }
}
```

prints

```
enum took 179 ns and memorize took 301 ns avg
enum took 74 ns and memorize took 97 ns avg
enum took 62 ns and memorize took 175 ns avg
enum took 58 ns and memorize took 146 ns avg
enum took 58 ns and memorize took 147 ns avg
enum took 56 ns and memorize took 111 ns avg
enum took 36 ns and memorize took 86 ns avg
enum took 36 ns and memorize took 84 ns avg
enum took 36 ns and memorize took 82 ns avg
enum took 36 ns and memorize took 82 ns avg
```

Comment: Aren't there situations where they need to be used together? The double check locking idiom comes to mind.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend you ever use the double checked idiom.  In these cases there is no suggestion of a specific performance requirement, so simplicity is far more likely to be useful.

Comment: Only one hit and run down voter, I thought there were two. ;)

Comment: Okay so your answer is just addressing the OP's specific use case, rather than saying `volatile` and `synchronized` should never mix? Also, I *have* read that the DCLI is hard to implement correctly, but what are its alternatives? I wasn't aware that it could always be avoided. See Guava's [`MemoizingSupplier`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.guava/guava/r09/com/google/common/base/Suppliers.java#Suppliers.MemoizingSupplier) for example.

Comment: I never use them and I have never come across a system which uses them.  But I have only been programming in Java for 14 years.  (I have worked for more than twenty companies in that time) ;)

Comment: e.g. Instead of a DCLI singleton, I use an `enum` with one instance.  Much simpler.

Comment: Developers who use Guava, tend to have a very different idea of simplicity to me. ;) Like I said an `enum Singleton { INSTANCE }` is simple, thread safe, lazy loading and the compiler and anyone reading it can see what it is doing exactly.  Or you could use MemozingSupplier with a anonymous inner class as a factory to a  which would not only be more complicated but slower.

Comment: Right, I also prefer the enum singleton pattern. But sometimes you need something lazily loaded *per instance*. Guava also has [`ExpiringMemoizingSupplier`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.guava/guava/r09/com/google/common/base/Suppliers.java#Suppliers.ExpiringMemoizingSupplier), for a more nuanced use case. Anyway I still feel like `volatile` and `synchronized` are independent tools with possible overlap. Thanks for the discussion.

Comment: @PaulBellora  Lazy loading can be over utilized in many systems.  Usually this is because no-one person really understands how the process works and cannot say how, or when a component is needed.  In a trading system (which is my area) the last thing you want is lazy loading as this leads to jitter, you want to do work eagerly so then you need to respond you can as quickly as possible.

Comment: @PaulBellora I use synchronized with volatile for my notify listeners. (where updating the listeners is synchronized, but notify is just a a volatile read)  However, this is a micro-optimisation which most people shouldn't entertain unless a) they really need to this because they measured it and b) they can be sure others in their team will understand it.  The last thing you want is write once only code.

Answer (score -1):

If you use `volatile` everywhere, you will be essentially introducing a lot of synchronization points in your code, which decrements efficiency.

When coding for concurrency, your best choice is to isolate shared mutability into small sections, or even eliminate shared state as much as possible.

Comment: The use of the `volatile` keyword itself does not incur locking and thus should not slow things down too bad.  Now, adding synchronization on top of that will...

Comment: @cmbaxter: excerpt from "Programming Concurrency on the JVM" by Venkat Subramaniam: "I call this [adding `volatile`] a quick fix because arbitrarily making all variables `volatile` may avoid the problem but will result in very poor performance because every access has to cross the memory barrier. Also `volatile` does not help atomicity when multiple fields are accessed, because the access to each of the `volatile` fields is separately handled and not coordinated into one access".

Comment: Very quick test: `for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) { long local = global++; }`, if `global` is volatile the total run time is around 74ms, if it is not `volatile`, total run time is 2ms. Bottom line, adding `volatile` introduces overhead, and does not guarantee atomicity (synchronization has to be added on top for most practical uses).